# How do I hold and drag to enlarge a window using Dell Precision touchpad

Tags: laptop, touchpad

I am using Windows 10 on Dell Precision laptop.

When I use a mouse, I point the cursor to the lower right corner of the window and the cursor shape changes, then I left-click-hold-n-drag it to enlarge the window.

How can I do that on touch pad? I opened the touch pad setup and do not see anything, all double finger, triple finger gestures are for simple moving.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double tap then hold and drag.

Meaning you point the pointer on the edge as you normally do then you tap and release then tap again and hold the finger on the touchpad.
Now you can move the finger around and drag the window size.